# Complex HTML table with multiple rowspan

Tags: html, html-table

I would like to make a bit complex HTML table with multiple `rowspan` values starting at different rows.

The HTML code below generates the attached screenshot, which is almost identical in Safari and Chrome.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="3">A</td>
     <td rowspan="2">B</td>
     <td rowspan="9">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="1">b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="1">a</td>
     <td rowspan="9">Y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="8">X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="2">c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="1">Z</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Safari rendering]

But what I would like to get is a table like below (please ignore unmerged cell borders).

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C |
| A | B | C |
| A | b | C |
| a | Y | C |
| X | Y | C |
| X | Y | C |
| X | Y | C |
| X | Y | C |
| X | Y | C |
| X | Y | c |
| X | Y | c |
| X | Y | Z |

How can I fix the code?

Comment: You write a function that transforms your code to the output you like. What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck? This is not a "We code it for you" service.

Comment: I don't do any programming for table layout transformation. What I want to know is how to use rowspan in a complex case. The markdown table shown at the bottom might be misleading, but it shows how many rows are occupied by individual characters, which shoul be merged by `rowspan`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue you will face here is that certain `tr` have no `td`. They still need to be declared even if there is no `td` because of the `rowspan`.

Also, declare the empty rows and it should work.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 3em;
}

tr {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <!-- Row 1 -->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="9">A</td>
    <td rowspan="2">B</td>
    <td rowspan="9">C</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Row 2 -->
  <tr></tr>
  <!-- Row 3 -->
  <tr>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Row 4 -->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="9">Y</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Row 5 -->
  <tr></tr>
  <!-- Row 6 -->
  <tr></tr>
  <!-- Row 7 -->
  <tr></tr>
  <!-- Row 8 -->
  <tr></tr>
  <!-- Row 9 -->
  <tr></tr>
  <!-- Row 10 -->
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td rowspan="2">c</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Row 11 -->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">X</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Row 2 -->
  <tr>
    <td>Z</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The original data that need to be converted to an HTML table is YAML. So I need to do something to count the number of empty rows...